# How to fix this errors in flutter when using with flutter_html_view plugin

Tags: dart, flutter

I am making a app in which i want to view a html page in flutter using flutter_html_view plugin ([LInK](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html_view)) I got an error here is the screenshot of the error message  [Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ4VB.jpg) here is the screenshot of the html  [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEnOt.jpg)
and here is the  the flutter code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_html_view/flutter_html_view.dart';
    class unit extends StatelessWidget {

    unit();
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String html = "<h3>Physical Quantities</h3> <p>Physical quantities may be divided in two classes:</p> <p>1. Scalar Quantities</p> <p>2. Vector Quantities</p> <p>-A scalar quantity is one which has only magnitude.</p> <p>-A vector quantity has both magnitude and direction.</p> <p>-Force, Velocity, Momentum, Acceleration are examples of vector quantities.</p> <p>-Mass, length, time, volume, speed, energy, work are examples of scalar quantities.</p> <p> </p> <h3>Units</h3> <p><br />-All measurements in physics require standard units.</p> <p>-In 1960, the General Conference of Weights and Measures recommended that a metric system of measurements called the International System of Units, abbreviated as SI units, be used.</p> <p> </p> <h3>Some Important Units</h3> <table style="height: 379px; width: 319px; border-color: #766B69;"> <tbody> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">S. No.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Units</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Quantity</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">1.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Metre</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Length</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">2.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Kilogram</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Mass</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">3.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Second</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Time</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">4.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Ampere</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Electric current</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">5.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Candela</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Luminous intensity</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">6.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Newton</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Force</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">7.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Joule</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Workdone</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">9.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Watt</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Power</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">10.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Coulomb</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Quantity of Electricity</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">11.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Volt</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Potential Difference</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">12.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Ohm</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Electrical Resistance</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 17px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 17px;">13.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 17px;">Henry</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 17px;">Inductance</td> </tr> <tr style="height: 26.05px;"> <td style="width: 59.2px; height: 26.05px;">14.</td> <td style="width: 84px; height: 26.05px;">Lumen</td> <td style="width: 155.2px; height: 26.05px;">Luminous Flux</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> <p> </p> <p>- Very small distances are measured in micro-meters or (microns)angstroms (A), nanometers (nm)       and femtometres (fm).</p> <p>- 1m=106µm=109nm= 10m A= 10'5 fm</p> <p>- 1 micron (lµ) = 10-4 cm = 10-6 m</p> <p>- 1 Angstrom (1 A) = 10-8 cm = 10-1° m </p> <p>- 1 Fermi (1F) = 10-13 cm = 10-'5 m</p> <p> </p>";
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Unit and measurement",style: new TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    ),),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: new SingleChildScrollView(
    child: new Center(
      child: new HtmlView(data: html),
      //child: new,
    ),
  ),
);
   }
   }
```

and here is the hlml code link [HTML code link](http://freetexthost.com/g2v2ak2j5g).
I think the error is occur due to the semicolon.I think due to I created a table for the hlml can anyone make this semicolon error fixed and  the is screenshot of the error message  [Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ4VB.jpg)

Comment: How can I display table border using this plugin??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart strings can be delimited with single *or* double quotes, for example `'Los Angeles'` or `"San Francisco"`. Strings surrounded with single quotes can contain double quotes, and vice versa. However, when you want to include the same variety of quote in the string you need to 'escape' it. See the [Language Tour](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#strings).

Since your HTML includes both double and single quotes you will need to excape something. Change the outer to single quotes

```
String html = '<h3>Physical Quantities</h3>
```

and then look for each single quote in the html and escape it like this

```
<p>- 1 Fermi (1F) = 10-13 cm = 10-\'5 m</p>
```

Eventually, you will presumably load the HTML from a URL or an asset, where you won't need to escape it. You need to escape it here as it is part of your source code.

Comment: Thank you for your  help now I am free of this error 

Comment: How can I display table border using this plugin? @Richard Heap